# Origin of the philosopher stone using human soul from an alchemical text in real life

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series, resources

I once read a few years back that the author got the idea of the philosopher stone being created by human sacrifice from a real life alchemical text.

If i recalled correctly the text is said to say that it require a sacrifice of a whole town or something along the line of that.

Anyone has any idea what the text/book is?

Comment: https://forum.becomealivinggod.com/t/philosophers-stone/32438/5 refers to human sacrifice but the poster might have gotten the idea from FMA.

Comment: Are you asking the inspirational origin if the series or the historical/archtypical concept? One of them is off-topic. Please clarify.